# contact us disappears when the class above it opens

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[before part&accecories open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXFfb.jpg)
[after part&accecories open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht47M.jpg)

code :[Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtM62.jpg)
[Css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTXcB.jpg)

```css
    
.nav-link .drop-menu{
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        background: #242526;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        border: none;
        background: #000;
        padding-left: 10px;
        display: none; 
    }
    .nav-link .mega-box{
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: static;
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        border: none;
        padding-left: 10px;
        display: none;
    }
    .mega-box .mega-links{
        border-left: none;
    }
    .nav-link li:hover .drop-menu,
    .nav-link li:hover .mega-box{
        top: 0px;
    }
    .drop-menu.open{
        display: block;
    }
   

 .mega-box.open{
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<li class="two"><a href="#">Part & Accecories</a>
  <ul class="mega-box">
    <ul class="mega-links">
      <img src="gambar/photo.jpg" alt="photo">
    </ul>
  <ul class="mega-links">
    <header>AmirCahyadi</header> 
      <div class="megalinks"> 
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      </div>
      </ul> 
         <ul class="mega-links">
         <header>AmirCahyadi</header>
         <div class="megalinks">
         <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
         </div>
         </ul>
         <ul class="mega-links">
         <header>AmirCahyadi</header>
         <div class="megalinks">
         <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
         </div>
         </ul>
         </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you give the full HTML of the entire nav bar?

Comment: https://github.com/Amir-cahyadi/Nav

Comment: You never closed the `div` with `</div>` for the first `megalinks`

Comment: still, the same sir when I've closed it now :(

Comment: I've added the code again with css

Comment: in the javascript, I only use the open class to open the parts & accessories section

Comment: Can you add your js code as well?

Comment: I'm not capable of replicate your nave bar in your images.  This is what I get using all the provided code: https://jsfiddle.net/sgpbkcxo/

Comment: I have given the complete one

Comment: When the product class sublist opens, contact us disappears to

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please take a look

Comment: whoah, this is working sir, one day I searched the way everywhere but it didn't work,
Thank you very much, you are really good.. :)

Comment: No Problem.  If my solution helped please give it an upvote and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.nav-link > li:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}
```